Switching 12V with 3.3V using a transistor, only lets 3.3V through from source to drain
I have an IRF540N transistor with which I want to switch 12 V with a 3.3 V signal coming from a Raspberry Pi Pico. When I measure before the transistor, I can detect 12V, but when I measure after the transistor I can only measure ~3.3 V.
When I switch source and drain, toggling the gate (with 3.3 V) doesn't change anything, 12 V always passes through the transistor.
Why is the transistor only letting through 3.3 V? (Respectively 12 V when switching drain and source.)

I made a photo of my schematic. You can see, at the top right the power supply providing 12 V. I also have a 12 V to 3.3 V voltage regulator, left of the Pico, with which I am powering the Pico. Left to that is the transistor with the gate connected to a pin of the Pico and source and drain toggling the flow of + to the LED module at the left of the transistor.


Please post a proper schematic diagram showing how these components are connected.

I think the schematics were left out. When adding images it's easy to miss pressing "add picture" after importing the picture

BTW, switching source and drain normally means the MOSFET will conduct all the time through its body diode.

Sounds like you’ve built a source follower. A schematic will tell.

You have built a source follower.
In a MOSFET, it is the voltage between the gate and the source that determines how much current flows.  If the voltage from source to gate is zero volts, then no current flows.
When you use a MOSFET as a source follower, the source will always be at or lower than the gate voltage.  With 3.3V on the gate, you can never get more than 3.3V on the source.
The usual way to use a N channel MOSFET to switch power is to switch to ground.  That is, you connect your circuit to 12V then use the MOSFET to complete the connection to ground.
